# RMI server java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, rmi, policyfiles

I'm building a RMI application and I have the following server class. However, when I run it in eclipse I get the following exception. What is wrong and how can I fix it? I've spent the last 2 days reading about similar problems online but I couldn't find the solution. I suspect it has something to do with a policy file, but I have no idea how to use one. Also if the problem is with the way I run it can you please give me directions for doing so in eclipse.

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory;
import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory;


public class MyServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Interface {

    private static final int PORT = 2019;

    public MyServer() throws Exception {
        super(PORT, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(), new SslRMIServerSocketFactory());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }

        try {

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(), new SslRMIServerSocketFactory());

            MyServer obj = new MyServer();


            registry.bind("HelloServer", obj);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

--

```
access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:2019" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:2019" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory$1.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Unknown Source)
    at MyServer.main(MyServer.java:27)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple.

```
access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:2019" "listen,resolve")
```

means that the policy file has to grant the permission

```
java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:2019", "listen,resolve"
```

or whatever the correct syntax is. Use the `policytool` to get it right. You may want to wildcard the port number. And you have to specify the location of the policy file via the `java.security.policy` system property. And when you get other access control exceptions, as you will in testing, you have to likewise add the corresponding permissions, until closure.

But I would rather ask why you're using a security manager at all. It isn't necessary unless you're going to use the codebase feature, which is fairly rare, and it isn't necessary in a server unless you're going to use the codebase feature to upload classes from the client, which is much rarer.